# How to merge all DLL files of a class library as one DLL (.NET Framework)?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have a task to merge multiple DLLs that come from build output of a class library (in /bin/Debug or /bin/Release folder) and ship them as a single DLL, meaning that this DLL will contain references to all other DLLs (third-party or not).
How can I do this programatically, using Assembly methods ?

Comment: ILMerge, Fody.Costura, LibZ, ...

Comment: IMO you shouldn't really do this at the *dll* level, because that breaks all the links - you kinda need to do this at the *application* level, i.e. at the topmost build that you're going to deploy - *then* you can just use the new full linker builds in .NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file), or ILMerge etc

Comment: The task says not to use third party libraries or nuget packages. I have heard that it can be solved using Assembly methods and events , but I don't have much information about this.

Comment: You can hook into [`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-5.0), and implement your own mechanism for packing assemblies together and then extracting them again, but this is an annoying and fragile task even when you're using tool which someone else has written and debugged. I wouldn't recommend trying to do this yourself.

Comment: I would say single file deployment would be the way to go if you are using a modern environment. Note that it basically unpacks all the dll-files to a temporary folder and runs the application from there, so relative paths may break. At least in the version I tried.

Comment: @Veri the single file deployment model that I've linked to: isn't third party or a nuget package, but honestly: that ("not to use third party libraries or nuget packages") is a silly requirement in the first place

Comment: @MarcGravell Not in all contexts. I work on medical software for example, and using a new third-party library comes with the burden of several days (to weeks, even) of analysis, documentation and validation, and an ongoing burden to monitor for bug reports and security issues. That's often more expensive than writing something yourself, certainly for small tasks.

Comment: I managed to merge DLL files as embedded resource to one DLL (called MergedDLL), using AssemblyResolve event, but when I try to use that Dll at another console application, I do not have access inside the embedded resources this merged Dll has. For example, this merged Dll contains another Dll of a class library I need to use, and I want to access its public methods/interfaces etc.. but it seems I cannot access them from this merged Dll.

Comment: @Veri have you got any solution?